# Why does EntityFramework return entire objects when I only ask for one column?

Tags: entity-framework

I am investigating slow performance over the network of my application which uses EntityFramework version 5. One option I tried was to retrieve only the Id field, instead of the entire object. However, examining in Wireshark, I see that all objects are transferred anyway. In other words, the following two code blocks cause exactly the same network activity. Would anyone know how I can cause the db to only return Ids in the first query?

```
List<long> test = dbContext.UserActivities
          .Where(ua => ua.Activity.Id == activityId)
          .Select(ua => ua.User)
          .ToList()
          .Select(u => u.Id)
          .ToList();

List<long> test = dbContext.UserActivities
          .Where(ua => ua.Activity.Id == activityId)
          .Select(ua => ua.User)
          .ToList();
```

Comment: `.ToList()` materializes the object. Essentially, executing the query. Anything after is LINQ to Objects.

Answer (score 4):

.ToList() materializes the object. Essentially, executing the query. Anything after is LINQ to Objects.

try something like this:

```
List<long> test = dbContext.UserActivities
          .Where(ua => ua.Activity.Id == activityId)
          .Select(ua => ua.User.Id).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
List<long> test = dbContext.UserActivities
          .Where(ua => ua.Activity.Id == activityId)
          .Select(ua => ua.User.Id).ToList();
```

Comment: I made a slight error on my query which you rightly corrected on yours (now fixed on mine). +1

Comment: That's exactly what I was missing.